# How to apply functools.lru_cache to function with mutable parameters?

Tags: python, memoization

I have a function with one of the parameters as numpy.ndarray. It's mutable so it can not be cached by lru_cache.

Is there any existing solution for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly the simplest way of doing so is to memoize a version taking only immutable objects.

Say your function takes an `np.array`, and let's assume it's a 1d array. Fortunately, it is easily translated to a `tuple`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>> tuple(a)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

and vice versa:

```
>> np.array(tuple(a))
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

So you get something like

```
# Function called by the rest of your program
array_foo(a) # `a` is an `np.array`
    ...
    return tuple_foo(tuple(a))
```

then memoize instead this function:

```
# Internal implementation
@functools.lru_cache
tuple_foo(t) # `t` is a tuple
    ...
    a = np.array(t)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is simple enough.

Comment: Doesn't doing a conversion every time negate the whole performance increase of memoizing?

Comment: @endolith It depends on what it's saving, no? If the operation is superlinear in the input (like inverting a dense matrix), it's probably going to be more efficient to cache, but for summing the entries of a matrix, no. Note that even w/o conversion, hashing the input would be linear. YMMV.

Comment: Another possibility is to compare inputs to cache using array.tobytes()